# iterating over std containers using standard for

Tags: c++, iterator, stdvector

From what I've learned the way to iterating over container, as std::vector, is by using iterators, as this:

```
for(vector<int>::iterator it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); it++)
```

My question is why not not iterating over container with standatd `for`, it is faster, because there is no need to call functions as `numbers.begin()`, and `numbers.end()`.
From what I tried, I found that using `for` is faster X 30, from using iterators.
I wrote this code:

```
vector<int> numbers;
for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
{
    numbers.push_back(i);
}

time_t t = time(0);
struct tm * now = localtime(&t);
cout << now->tm_hour << ":" << now->tm_min << ":" <<  now->tm_sec << "\n";

for(vector<int>::iterator it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); it++)
{
    *it = 7;
}

t = time(0);
now = localtime(&t);
cout << now->tm_hour << ":" << now->tm_min << ":" <<  now->tm_sec << "\n";

int size = numbers.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    numbers[i] = i;
}

t = time(0);
now = localtime(&t);
cout << now->tm_hour << ":" << now->tm_min << ":" <<  now->tm_sec;
```

The output is:

```
    19:28:25
    19:28:56
    19:28:57
```

Comment: You seem to believe that standard containers are indexable (i.e. `numbers[i]`), that is certainly not the norm but the exception

Comment: You are using "standard" `for` in both cases in your example.

Comment: Did you enable compiler optimizations?  There might be a huge difference in behavior of `vector<T>::iterator` between a debug build and a release build.

Comment: @K-ballo - What do you mean? it is wrong to approach an element by index? it works fine!

Comment: @Nikos - I mean without iterators.

Comment: @user1544067: It works only for `vector` and I believe `dequeue`, it does not work for `set`, `map`, `list`, `forward_list`, etc... Indexability is not one of the requirements for a standard conformant container

Comment: @aschepler - You right, but also with release it still faster X 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your numbers -- 30 seconds to iterate a simple vector?  That's an eternity in CPU time.  There's something wrong there.

Some suggestions:

- The vector takes ~19MB.  That's not much but it's possible that it could cause heap fragmentation, or maybe VM swapping if you had many other apps loaded on your computer.  To get a reliable number, close as many apps as possible and make sure your system is idle.
- The couts are inside the timer, so you're measuring the performance of parts of the iostream library.  Do the couts outside the timed section, *after* you take the stop time.
- A one-second clock isn't precise enough for performance metrics.  Use timeval and gettimeofday() to get micro-second precision.
- With only one iteration of the vector, I was seeing big diffences between runs.  To get more repeatable results, iterate the vector multiple times (like 500 times).  (This is better than using a larger vector, which might cause swapping/fragmentation issues.)
- Turn on optimizations (e.g., g++ -O3).  The loops will ran much faster and the time difference will be much less.  Inline optimizations probably help the std::vector<> code more.

With these changes (below), on my computer, iterators were 4x slower than indicies without optimizations but slightly *faster* with -O1 and pretty much the same with -O3.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

const unsigned N_REPS = 500;
const unsigned N_ITEMS = 5000000;

int print_elapsed(timeval start)
{
    timeval stop;
    gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);
    int elapsed = (stop.tv_sec * 1000000 + stop.tv_usec) - (start.tv_sec * 1000000 + start.tv_usec);
    cout << elapsed << "us" << endl;
    return elapsed;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> numbers;
    numbers.reserve(N_ITEMS); // avoid heap fragmentation
    for (int i = 0; i < N_ITEMS; ++i)
        numbers.push_back(i);

    timeval start;
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    for (unsigned r = 0; r < N_REPS; ++r)
        for (vector<int>::iterator it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); ++it)
            *it = r;

    int elapsed0 = print_elapsed(start);
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    unsigned size = numbers.size();
    for (unsigned r = 0; r < N_REPS; ++r)
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            numbers[i] = r;

    int elapsed1 = print_elapsed(start);
    cout << 100 * float(elapsed1) / elapsed0 << '%' << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you summarize better to use standatd for, without iterators?

Comment: With this compiler (gcc 4.4.6), with optimizations enabled, there is no meaningful performance difference between using iterators and simple integer indices.  I suspect that will be true for other compilers.  So my recommendation would be to enable optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Using iterators provide you the flexibility that even if you change the container type to another the iterating code will remain the same. This is because all the standard library containers provide iterators. In a way it gives you the chance to write more ***generic*** code.

Comment: But what better way to iterating over container?